# dy not changing in span element in js

Tags: javascript, css, styling

I am changing the dy of my span elements in my JS code. When I change the dy in the chrome developer tools, it looks correct like this screenshot of correct format with correct dy values:

[image]

I have the following code in js to create this effect:

```
  var myEle = document.getElementById("dynamicsubtitle1");
    myEle && myEle.parentNode.removeChild(myEle);

    var chart = this,
    rend = chart.renderer,
    pie = chart.series[0],
    left = chart.plotLeft + pie.center[0],
    top = pie.center[1] + 20;
    if(!rend.getElementById)
    var text = rend.text('<span class="pietitle" style="color:#000; vertical-align:top; text-align:center">' + "Total<br>" 
            + '<span class="pietitle" style="color:#000; vertical-align:top; text-align:center" position:"relative"  dy="1vw">' + "Incidents<br>"
            + '<span class="piedata" dy="2vw" style="color:#000; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; font-weight:bold">' + this.series[0].total, left, top).attr({
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'id': 'dynamicsubtitle1',
        'zIndex': 10
      }).addClass('customTitle').add();
```

However, it is turning out like this (Screenshot where dy is defaulting back to 15)

[image]

I have tried to get the same effect in CSS with line-height and with margins, but neither seems to apply no matter what I try. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the chart library you are using which will turn `<span>` in `<tspan>`. Does it have a documentation?

Comment: @Kaiido unfortunately not. I'm using a third party configuration which my company chose. I know they build off of hicharts but that's it.